# using realloc in c 1

Tags: c, realloc

I don't know what's the problem in this code-

```
void initialize(char ***A, int r, int c){
*A = (char **)realloc(A,sizeof(char *)*r);
}
```

this is the call-

```
char **A;
initialize(&A, 10, 10);
printf("%c",A[1][1]);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Major confusion. Sorry I cannot write an extensive answer on this smartphone.

Comment: A is null at first and I want to pass it to the function. If I do "malloc" it works but if I do malloc it doesn't.

Comment: OT: At least `int r` should better (nicer) be `size_t r`.

Comment: Even if the (re-)allocation would work, then this `printf("%c",A[1][1]);` still would fail, as the allocation does not provide memory for for `*A` points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A is uninitialized, try initializing it with `NULL`:

```
char **A = NULL;
initialize(&A, 10, 10);
```

`realloc()` will behave like `malloc()` in that case and will correctly `realloc()` in further calls. Otherwise, an uninitialized pointer will be dereferenced by `realloc()`.

Furthermore, `realloc()` `*A`:

```
realloc(*A, sizeof(char *) * r);
```

Otherwise, you would try to realloc the pointer to the pointer of your allocated space A, which will of course fail.

Comment: ... or just do the more robust: `*A = realloc(*A, r * sizeof **A);`

Comment: @rotemhas: If this answered you question you want to accept this answer by clicking its check-mark.